# How to find files/directories with specific ACL

Tags: find, acl

How to do something like

```
find . -acl u:jim:rx
find . -acl u:*:r
find . -noacl u:jim:r
```

etc.

I know that the find command does not support this but, you have the idea. Are there any scripts, even for some specific scenarios?

**Note 1**: I am particulary intereseted in debian, but it applies to any *nix OS.

**Note 2**: This question focuses on a practical case, but in fact is much more general - what are the good tools for finding files in connection to ACL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getfacl` tool with `-R`ecursive option, `-s`kipping files that only have the base ACL and pipe the output to `grep`.

For example the following command run under `/dev` directory gives for me:

```
$ getfacl -Rs . | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/\nuser:jimmij:rw-\n/'

# file: sg1
# owner: root
# group: cdrom
user::rw-
user:jimmij:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

# file: sr0
# owner: root
# group: cdrom
user::rw-
user:jimmij:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

(...)
```

To get just the file names printed:

```
getfacl -Rs . | awk -v RS= '/\nuser:jimmij:rw-\n/ {sub(/\n.*/, ""); sub(/^[^:]*: /, ""); print}'
```

Comment: Thanks! I have [found](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) that unsetting `RS` with `-v RS=` separates records on blank lines. However the filename extration part is really difficult for me to understand. How do you do it?

Comment: I beleive there was a mistake in a code. I made a correction.

Comment: The question wasn't specifically tagged with Linux, but this answer does not work on BSD *nix: `getfacl: illegal option -- R`. I suppose you could use `find . -exec getfacl {} \;` and pipe the output of that to `awk`.  Though BSD does not have the `-s` option either, so it's probably not going to work.